# Eclipse GWT ClassCastException

Tags: eclipse, gwt, smartgwt

I have a smart gwt application. It was running fine and then i logged in and now my stuff does not run in Eclipse. If i build from commandline and deploy the app it works.

I am not sure how to debug the issue or trace what is going on. Any ideas what i can look at. I do worry that the eclipse gwt plugin i am using might have been updated and this is causing the issue but i am not sure what to rule in or out. Thanks for any help.

```
com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.Long to field com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.SourceOrigin.fileName of type java.lang.String in instance of com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.SourceOrigin
    at com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:2060)
    at com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:2045)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager.syncReadDiskCache(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager.getCache(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.doCompile(Recompiler.java:357)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:175)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.recompile(Recompiler.java:134)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.recompile(Outbox.java:135)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.recompile(JobRunner.java:113)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.access$000(JobRunner.java:37)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner$2.run(JobRunner.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.Long to field com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.SourceOrigin.fileName of type java.lang.String in instance of com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.SourceOrigin
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2284)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JsSourceMap.readObject(JsSourceMap.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1409)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager$2.call(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:176)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCacheManager$2.call(MinimalRebuildCacheManager.java:162)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Yes - i see that but which datasource? This is not just one datasource and tracking this down is not obvious. I kind would like to see what is failing specifically. I am also confused why when i run this outside of eclipse it does not have an issue.

Comment: The problem is in [code server](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gwt-dev-2.8.2/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/CodeServer.html) for Super Dev Mode (dev as developement or debug mode). That is why the compiled (production mode) application is not affected. Check your configuration and GWT / GXT version.

Comment: So i am looking over the code and my changes and nothing is jumping out at me - how does one figure out where the error is. I even started to put breakpoints in the gwt classes to see what it might be referring to but everything is so detached that i cant tell much at all.

Comment: and thanks for your help - this get stress full when all i want to do is finish my work and have to deal with this. so thank you for all your help

Comment: It could be a mix of verions, like your code server deps vs gwt deps,or might be your java version, how do you build the app? ant, maven...? how to do you add dependencies? this information might help